# Test Gasoline for Water Content

Tags: fuel-system, testing

I live in a small town, and the Gas station there has a bad reputation for gas quality. With rumors like peoples gas tanks freezing solid and such.

Is there a quick, safe, cheap way to test for water content in gasoline so we can put the final word on these rumors? Our regular gasoline is E10.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Water in fuel is easy to figure out. Put a sample (say 5 to 10 ounces) of the fuel into a clear glass container. Let it sit. If it separates into two layers, you have water in the fuel.

[image: demonstration of water and gasoline separating]

Shown: an obviously contrived example of gasoline (10% ethanol) with approximately 2 ounces of water added - water has visibly sunk to the bottom of the jar.

Comment: Any guidance on how long you need to wait?

Comment: I'd assume it's similar to Avgas, which separates at the rate of around an inch a minute (Foot deep fuel tank will end up with all the water on the bottom in 12 minutes).

Comment: Will the water still separate out with the 10% ethanol? I know that has some effect on the water solubility.

Comment: I would *guess* so, but can't say for certain.  I only fly certified airplanes, and any ethanol at all is prohibited in them.  However, the experimental guys in the hangar next door have a Rotax that's allowed to run 5% ethanol.  They're still technically required to sump the fuel for water, so I'm guessing it still separates in a similar manner?  Either way, it's an empirical question.  Stick some of your gas in a cup and drop in some water to see what happens.  :-)

Comment: I am fairly certain that this would still work for 10% ethanol. The last time I did this was before they started adding ethanol. You could always do a test run by getting some of the gas and pouring a bit of water in it to see if it separates with the ethanol, and so you know what to look for.

Comment: Ethanol is hygroscopic (it absorbs water). As such, gasoline with ethanol in it will _not_ separate as completely as gasoline without ethanol.  With enough water content, it will still separate, but the "gasoline" portion will still contain some unseen water.  See [here](http://www.fuel-testers.com/expiration_of_ethanol_gas.html) for some more info. This site suggests you might be able to cool your sample (in the fridge or freezer?) to render more of the water (but also some ethanol) insoluble.

Comment: maybe i should split the question, but any test that also indicate if 91oct is 91oct?

Comment: Flying with ethanol in the fuel? A good Pilot attempts to reduce the number of known potential problems. If you fly with ethanol, you likely fly with a pilot who knows less than he should.

Answer (score 0):

most diesel vehicles have a fuel/water separator some with an audible alarm if not 
they are available aftermarket.Be worth enquiring if these are compatible with gasoline
engines